# Hlint integration with emacs not working on new machine

Tags: emacs, hlint

I use hlint from within emacs with [hs-lint.el](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Haskell_mode_for_Emacs#Integration_with_HLint) in exactly the manner described in the link.

hlint lives in my ~/.cabal/bin directory, which is on my $PATH, and everything works as expected when I call it from the command line.  When I set this up on a new machine and tried to invoke it within emacs, however, I get the following message in the minibuffer:

```
error in process sentinel: Moved past last error
```

and the following in an `*hs-lint*` buffer:

```
-*- mode: hs-lint; default-directory: "/home/wvoq/project/" -*-
HLint started at Fri Jan 13 02:48:53

hlint /home/wvoq/project/myfile.hs
/bin/bash: hlint: command not found

HLint exited abnormally with code 127 at Fri Jan 13 02:48:53
```

From my understanding, there's no reason that bash should have trouble finding hlint.  Is there?

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you launch Emacs from a desktop shortcut the `PATH` that it has is not the `PATH` that your shell has.  If you launch Emacs from a shell you should be able to confirm that this is the problem.  There are many ways to fix it.  For example, on OS X you can add environment variables to `~/.MacOSX/environment.plist`.  Or you can set `PATH` inside Emacs with something like:

```
(setenv "PATH" (concat "~/.cabal/bin:" (getenv "PATH")))
(add-to-list 'exec-path "~/.cabal/bin")
```

Comment: Yep, the first line was sufficient to resolve it for me. Thanks again.

Comment: You can also just start Emacs on OS X normally and use an elisp library called [exec-path-from-shell](https://github.com/purcell/exec-path-from-shell) to set Emacs' $PATH to match that seen in the shell. Installable packages are available in Marmalade and [Melpa](http://melpa.milkbox.net/).